# DataContext is set to the string value of DataContext but not the actual object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-5

I moved from .NET Core 3.1 to .net 5 and now the `DataContext` is set to the string value of `DataContext`, not the actual object with the name of string value:

```
Title="Hello World" Height="450" Width="800" DataContext="viewModel">
```

`viewModel` is definied in the `Window` class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
```

This worked with .NET Core 3.1 but not with .NET 5. Setting the `DataContext` in code-behind via `this.DataContext = viewModel` works.

The Binding errors:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Input' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-1596770601)'. BindingExpression:Path=Input; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-1596770601); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='tbInput'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Input' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-1596770601)'. BindingExpression:Path=Input; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-1596770601); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Comment: `DataContext="viewModel"` assigns the string `"viewModel"` to the DataContext property, regardless of the WPF or .NET version. You may let the MainWindow class expose a `ViewModel` property and write `DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that this is an issue with .NET 5. The error is that the following line assigns the string literal `viewModel` to the `DataContext`:

```
DataContext="viewModel"
```

It does **not** assign or bind an instance of your `ViewModel` type.

> Setting the DataContext in code behind via this.DataContext = viewModel works.

Of course this works, because now you assign an instance of the `ViewModel` type and not a `string`. Alternatively, you could create and assign the `ViewModel` instance in XAML directly like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

If you wanted to bind an instance defined in your window, you would have to expose a **public property**, because you cannot bind to fields as in your current definition. As per naming convention, properties are written in Pascal Case, starting with a capital letter.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public ViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new ViewModel();

   // ...other code.
}
```

Then you could bind it in XAML like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```